# Why is this computer so slow?

Tags: firefox, chromium, opera

How can I speed up my Aspire ONE D250 manufacturing date 0911 (09 or 11?)?

Details:

- Memory: 2.0GB
- Processor: Intel® Atom™ CPU N270 @ 1.60GHz × 2
- Graphics: Intel® 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2
- OS Type: 32-bit
- Disk: 155.3 GB
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I think it has become gradually slower in the last year. Now I have to wait for websites to load.

I often use several tabs in three separate browsers:  Chromium, Firefox 50.1.0, and Opera 12.16.

Is the computer too old to cope with this workload?

Comment: Are you using an Ubuntu derivative? If so, please state what one.

Comment: Well, it definitely is old and weak hardware and the requirements nowadays by even simple applications are increasing all the time. Especially websites become more and more complex and resource-heavy. The only thing you could do if you don't want to replace the machine yet is to install a more lightweight desktop environment like XFCE (Xubuntu) or LXDE (Lubuntu).

Comment: @ByteCommander Ubuntu MATE also runs fine on computers of that spec.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced a similar situation with a Dell Inspiron 1545 w similar hardware specs running Ubuntu 14.04, I opted to try another light version. Installed XUbuntu 16.04 and can recommend you to try this as well. Boot up improved, browsers behave much better, general performance enhancements. For me, it was definitely worth the move. I dual boot with Grub2 and fortunately had no difficulty with that setup. If you need any third party drivers, (I needed the driver for my Broadcom wireless card) that will have to be reinstalled as well, so bone up on that install, again if necessary, before making the move. IT IS worth it to back up documents, pictures, music, and videos (I was able to do a copy of these items to my home network - or can back up to a USB stick OR to a CD/DVD). Hope this helps Craig

Comment: I remember having tried Lubuntu a while ago for a netbook and ran into issues like the one you mention. Is it worth my time? is the question that no one else can answer I suppose.

Comment: Actually, it depends on what you finally want. If the PC's current performance is 'driving you buggy' then I would say do it.